# Bootstrap tabs don't need explicit js?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3. The [tab docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) say

> > Enable tabbable tabs via JavaScript (each tab needs to be activated individually)

The docs say to add an on-click to each tab to prevent the click default and to show the tab. But they also say that adding `data-toggle` will work.

And the following appears to work *great* in Chrome, IE, FF.
The first pill is selected by default; clicking any other pill fades in the right content.

**Q: do I need to add additional js to properly "enable" the pills? Is this a doc error or do I need to do more?**

**Added** PS. I certainly realize that JS is needed to make the tabs work. My Q is about what explicit JS scripts, if any are needed to get the tabs up and running in a vanilla case.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="pill">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="pill">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="pill">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="home">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap has bootstrap.js that should/will attach events automatticaly based on certain data-* attributes if present

Comment: Thanks @PatrickEvans -- So it's a doc error? Ie **Either** enable via javascript or via the data attributes?

Comment: Pastrick is right, of course. Tabs dont need _additional_ javascript for working, eg showing tabs from by the markup, but you must certainly go around the docs if you want to say store and save tab-position.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, pls submit your comment as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the **Markup** portion of the tab docs it says

> *"You can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript"*

So that is letting you know that you can do it either through javascript or just by setting a data-* attribute. Most if not all of Bootstraps javascript features act like this you can either enable functionality through writing out the javascript events our letting Bootstrap do it by just providing the correct data-* attributes.

`bootstrap.js` has functions that run and will automatically setup events based on these attributes if present.

Comment: I was mislead by the docs' saying "enable" in one place and "activate" in another. Thank you for the answer.